# how to load cURL library in views Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, curl

How to load cURL library in codeigniter views.

I tried loading in controller

```
function image() {
   $json = $_REQUEST['json'];
   $data['results'] = $json;
   $this->load->library('curl');
   $this->load->view('image', $data);
}
```

but I am unable to parse the json content in the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has its own way of decoding JSON, namely via the json_decode() method. You can find the specification for the method over here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

I might be able to provide a more accurate answer if you post some view code. Anyway, you would need to adapt your code:

```
$data['results'] = json_decode($json);
```

JSON decoding is available since PHP 5.2.

Comment: @Ramaraju.d Cool, nice to hear it worked! Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create  a instance

```
$CI = &get_instance();
$CI->load->library('curl');
```